# Logitech C670i webcam stopped working starting with Big Sur

Tags: webcam

Any web application (Zoom, Photobooth, etc) not only fails with the external Logitech webcam connected, but the built-in FaceTime camera does not work with the webcam connected. The image flickers and then stops working completely until I disconnect the Logitech camera.

Troubleshooting:

- The external camera works fine with non macOS devices.
- When connecting the device, I can see it detected as a USB device.
- Tried different USB ports, and external hubs with same results.

What can I try next?

Comment: First thing to do is check for updates. Many things stopped working with Big Sur & needed software/firmware/driver updates

Comment: Where exactly does the camera *not* work? Only in browsers or also if you open Photobooth?

Comment: There are no dedicated downloads for this camera.
Any application, Photobooth, browsers, Zoom, etc.
It won't just not work, but also render the built in came useless as well, untill disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Big Sur upgrade my Logitech Streamcam stopped working too, but only when connected via USB-A adapter (even though it worked just fine in older MacOS versions). It does work fine in Big Sur when I use the Type-C connection though. Weird...

In general, I see a lot of people complaining about BigSur/Logitech issues, no staight-forward solution yet but some people indicated that installing [Logi Options+ Beta](https://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/software/logi-options-plus.html) solved their problems. You might as well give it a try and let us know the result =)

Comment: Unbelievable! You are correct. Plugging the camera directly into the computer makes it work.
I won't bother with the beta program, also Logi Options is meant for keyboards and mice, not cameras. Thank you!

Comment: @Boris I'm glad I could be useful ;-)